# Toggle between tow divs on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need something like this: http://www.java2s.com/example/html-css/css-widget/show-div-and-hide-another-on-hover-with-transition.html

except that I need the div where I hover over (trigger) to be the same as the one that gets removed (and returns if I move the mouse away).

In my case I have a div that shows a card with a logo & headline (using bootstrap 5).

When I hover over that card, I want to change the content of the card to be a information text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css before with content and dispaly it when hovering
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before